# How do I list the count of orders in each nation, along with the nation name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for orders, a table for nations, and a table for customers. I am trying to get the # of orders by country. I tried

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (
        nation
        INNER JOIN customer ON nation.n_nationkey = customer.c_nationkey
    )
    INNER JOIN orders ON customer.c_custkey = orders.O_CUSTKEY
```

but it doesn't give me what I want. How do I get the amount of nations with the number of orders from each one?

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Comment: Show the data structure. We don't know your column names.

Comment: You should post a description for each table. Give an overview of how tables are connected. What you have tried so far and which is the problem you are facing.

Comment: The parenthesis in your `JOIN` expression is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need a group by and at least one column listed in that clause e.g.

```
SELECT
      nation.n_nationkey, COUNT(*) order_count
FROM nation
INNER JOIN customer ON nation.n_nationkey = customer.c_nationkey
INNER JOIN orders ON customer.c_custkey = orders.O_CUSTKEY
GROUP BY
     nation.n_nationkey
```

This will cause he query to produce one row for each unique value of `n_nationkey` and will count all rows related to the `n_nationkey` value of each row. Add or substitute the nation name column in the selct and group by clauses.

Comment: Seems straightforward enough. One note: this pattern won't return a "zero" count for a nation, that is, a nation with zero orders will be omitted from the result. To get zero counts, we'd need outer joins to customer and orders, and then count an expression that will be non-NULL for each matched order, e.g. `COUNT(orders.O_CUSTKEY) AS order_count`

Comment: @spencer7593 is correct, if you need nations with zero orders the join types have to change to `left join` instead of `inner join`